# How to draw text inner shadow on Cocoa for Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

How do I draw an inner shadow on a text in Cocoa for Mac OS X?

I am subclassing NSView to create a placeholder control with a gradient background and an inner shadowed text title over it.

All current Core Graphics answers on stackoverflow seem to explain drawing text shadows on Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might think too complicated. If I get your problem right, the only thing you actually want to do is to set the text style. Then do so by simply using:

```
[[object cell] setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleRaised];
```

where object is an instance of the class NSTextField.

This handles everything for you. Your gradient background then could be reached for example by using a custom view with a NSGradient. See [here](http://igaret.com/tutorials/gradient-windows-in-cocoa)

Advantage: You have a proper instance of NSTextField without the need to subclass it or to do other unneeded things like implementing everything a NSTextField does in a subclass of NSView on your own.

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for. Sadly I had to subclass NSView and override drawrect to achieve a similar effect, Will consider refactoring it for sure.